# How to pause a running Python script and resume after changing a line (on Windows)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

To my knowledge there is no solution to obtain a short-lived access token from Facebook using Python.

I need a "short-lived" because I don't have an old version long-lived (v. 2.3).

Now my question is: Is there a way that I can pause my running Python script after e.g. 10000 queries in order to change short-lived access token manually and then resume the script?

I'm going to collect all posts from some Facebook pages. Therefore, it takes more than 2 or 3 hours for each page!

Comment: Can't you just put an input() statement right at where you want to pause it? And once you are done manually changing something, just hit, <Enter>?

Comment: @Joe, Thank you! It should be a great solution! Now I'm tying to do that!

Comment: _“I need a "short-lived" because I don't have an old version long-lived”_ – no clue what you mean by that. Of course you can use short-lived or extended tokens the same way, even in higher API versions.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for your Answer! some information are not available anymore in new versions. For Instance, you cannot see the pages that the page has liked in new versions.

Comment: But what does the API version have to do with whether you use a short-lived or an extended token? (Correct answer: Nothing whatsoever of course.)

Comment: _“For Instance, you cannot see the pages that the page has liked in new versions”_ – of course you can, via `/page-id/likes`

Comment: access_token = "X" , graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token, version='Y'), the extended token (X) you use must be the same with the Y!    But using the short-live you can use the version you want!

Comment: using v. 2.4 or newer you have to use a new query for each data you want. e.g. if you want to know the "category" of page, "about" of page, "description" of page you have to create a new query for each one of them which is very Time-consuming and you will reach very soon the limit that Facebook has defined! But using v. 2.3 you'll get all of these data just via a query!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
def get_new_token():
    input("Input new token into file and press enter")
    with open('file', 'r') as f:
        query(next(f))

def query(token):
    for i in range(1,10000):
        do_your_thing()
    get_new_token()
```